# Unable to login from GUI?

Tags: 13.10, login, lightdm, login-screen, system

Running 13.10 x64 on an Ubuntu laptop (System 76 Kudu Professional).

When I bootup and provide my password; the screen goes black for a moment then returns to the login screen.

Switching tty I am able to login; then start X (using `startx` or `startx unity`).

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

My `/etc/environment` was corrupted; fixing that solved this issue.

Comment: Can you explain how you did that?

Comment: I rsync'd the `/etc/environment` from one of my servers; replacing my own with that one.